# Add markers to a div element in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, double-click, marker

I need a marker that behaves much like adding a marker to a map. On double click cause a marker to be displayed at the point that was clicked, and returns the x/y pixel coordinates of the point that was clicked.

I want to be able to add those markers into div element (`<div id="paper"></div>`) that has got map drawn in javascript already.

Any help here is much appreciated!

Comment: No i am not using. My map is not exactly map of a land.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#paper").dblclick(function(e) {
    var relativeX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var relativeY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    var marker = $('<img>').addClass('marker'); //your marker class
    marker.css({
        left: relativeX,
        top: relativeY
    })
    marker.appendTo(this);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a tutorial on jquery.com for exactly that question.

http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position

Answer (score 1):

In pseudocode

```
$("#paper").dblclick(function(e) {
    x, y = calculate mouse position from e.pageX/Y and $(this).offset
    marker = $(marker html code).appendTo(this)
    marker.css({ left: x, top: y})
})
```

Comment: And where element marker has CSS position: absolute, if you calculate x and y relative to the page; or where both marker and div#paper have position: relative, if you calculate x and y relative to the top left corner of #paper.